# How do I parse a json/javascript date with timezone to C# DateTime?

Tags: javascript, .net, json

How do I parse this date format:

> /Date(1402537043438+1000)/

to a C# DateTime?

I'm limited to .Net 3.5 and can't use a nuget package like Newtonsoft.

Comment: [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) should be able to read that format

Comment: I get an excpetion "Invalid JSON primitive: ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) (an external assembly, of sorts, but not a NuGet requirement) can parse those dates, but they need to have a `\` at the start and end of the string, e.g.:

```
var date = "/Date(1402537043438+1000)/";
var parsedDate = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTime>("\"" + date.Replace("/", "\\/") + "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm more than happy to use use Framework stuff, but my string isn't _quite_ in that format. Your's has some characters that are lacking in mine, specifically the leading escaped quotes and  the additional backslashes

Comment: @Ev. Yup, that's right. Your date is what I have in the `date` variable. What I'm doing is modifying that variable to make it a valid JSON format for the serializer

Comment: I have just seen your update and I expect it to work. Seems kind of wacky that that string isn't more easily converted. Do you think that suggests my data is bad?

Comment: Your data is fine, this is the format MS uses to represent a Date in JSON (it's actually the format the `JavaScriptSerializer` will serialize *to*) because JSON doesn't actually specify a way to handle Dates. It seems wacky, because it technically is just a wacky workaround to a limitation of the JSON format :)